# jQuery setting the css "color" element of another item overrides its hover pseudoclass

Tags: html, jquery, css, hover, pseudo-class

I wanted to have one element highlight either when it gets hovered, or some other element is also hovered. Yet the code i've written to achieve this seems to override the hover pseudo-class whenever it gets run. I can't seem to see why -- minimal example in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mLynfz3x/

As soon as the second element gets hovered, the hover pseudo class for the first one is removed, and I'm not sure why. Is it intended that the jQuery `.css()` function override pseudo-classes? Or is the issue something else that I've missed entirely

Thank you!

Comment: Pseudo-elements are not part of the `DOM`, so they can't be change or returned to the original state using jQuery or Javascript. As soon as you hover over them `.css` takes full control of the element.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping that's exactly why I'm confused as to how jQuery/js code is somehow removing or disabling my pseudo-elements

Comment: So you got the answer ? I am not sure what confusing about this ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I misread your comment. I wasn't sure what you meant by 'hover over them' in your second sentence. So it is indeed `.css()` that is messing them up?

Comment: Correct! .css will take out the element and will not listen to pseudo element defined for that element.

Comment: Okay, thank you :)

Comment: the alternative to that i was about add here (see an answer below as well) would make something `!important` in your CSS - but personally i do not like adding !important unless super necessary.

Comment: I strongly agree with @AlwaysHelping here cause it's overriding existing CSS and thats just not very "clean". I usually create a class with the wanted effect and if i want to achieve css changes with JQuery i use .addClass() and .removeClass() or .toggleClass() to change the applied css without getting redundant code

Answer (score 2):

The set Color for the Element Testlink doesnt disable the hover-pseudo class, the fixed color for that element is just, lets say "higher priority". So all you  gotta do to fix it is add:

```
#testLink:hover {
  color: olive !important;
}
```

and it should work with your existing JQuery.

Comment: That is caused by the fact, that .css() adds INLINE-Style to your element, and that has higher priority than stylesheets, if that explains your question

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did

```
$("#aTestItem").hover(() => {
  $("#testLink").css("color", "olive");
}, () => {
  $("#testLink").css("color", "black");
});

$("#testLink").hover(() => {
  $("#testLink").css("color", "olive");
}, () => {
  $("#testLink").css("color", "black");
});
```